# Unity 3D Game sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite-sheet

I need some good **sprites for game development** on unity. 
Action game project is quite good for me. There is only one better resource for it: 
[open game art](http://opengameart.org/)

But I want some more better resource for a game.

Answer (score 1):

http://spritedatabase.net/
http://www.spriters-resource.com/

And Google Images works fine!

P,S, Try to make them by your self, Just try some little things, There are a lot of tutorials if you don't understand some things.